# Why is my array filtering handler nor working as expected?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a handler that filters through an array of objects set inside the state and I'm passing it to a child component that has 3 sections. In each of the sections I'm calling the handler and passing it the value which is used for filtering:

The handler looks like this:

```
addSectionConfigsHandler = config => {
  const configs = this.state.usedComponents.filter(
    item => item.group === config
  );

  return configs;
};
```

inside the child component I'm calling it once for each of the 3 sections like this:

```
<div label="Header"/>
  <AddSectionItems
    configs={props.configs("header")}
    droppableId="header"
  />
</div>
<div label="Content">
  <AddSectionItems
    configs={props.configs("body")}
    droppableId="content"
  />
</div>
<div label="Footer">
  <AddSectionItems
    configs={props.configs("footer")}
    droppableId="footer"
  />
</div>
```

The usedComponents array contains multiple objects that look something like this:

```
{
  id: 0,
  group: "header",
  ...
}
```

I expect to get 3 arrays that contain objects filtered for header, body and footer, which I then want to map, but it's not working as expected.
Inside my state I have 4 objects that should match for header and 3 that should match for footer, and I do get 3 arrays, however only the body array returns all the objects that match for body, while header and footer arrays return only 1 object.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post the details of <AddSectionItems> to see where addSectionConfigsHandler is called.

Comment: It's called right there in the second code snippet. It's then passed to the <AddSectionItems> as an array that I want to map.

Comment: Need to look more into your code to see where you are going wrong. But i have tried implementing what you are trying to achieve and here's the stackblitz example.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eay1ve

Comment: Damn! I just figured out that I was pulling the data from the wrong state array. usedComponents is an array of components that are active. I was supposed to pull the data from the components array.